# Number combinations program?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

My question is the following: I want to write a program that can calculate how many combinations in a given digit.

For example: 
How many number combinations in 5 digits? 
Which is 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 = 120 combinations!

Comment: What issues are you having writing the program?

Comment: Example: function combinations(n) {
                // code..
                return numberOfCombinations;
                }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "combination."  Can you explain this?

Comment: Note, no question actually appears at OP. _"I want to write a program"_ is not a question.

Comment: so you want to calculate 5 factorial ?

Comment: Sry if my question was not clear, it's the following, i want to write a function that you pass a number n ( for example: 12345 ) and you return all the combinations of that number. ( for example: 123 have 6 combination: 3 x 2 = 6 )

Comment: That still is not a question. "i want" is not a question

Comment: Pass n to a function, and function return all the combinations of that number. That's all !
As i said a number n = 12345 for example have 120 combination !

Comment: What issues are you having composing the code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand you right, i Think this is what you want:

```
var n = <number>
Math.pow(10,n);
```

This calculates how many deferent combinations you can have in *n* digits

Comment: I already solved this problem thx for help anyway :)

Comment: @Elight7 can you please mark this as the correct answer and close the question?

Comment: @McMuffin What combinations do you (and author ,if you understand him) mean? For example, I see 90 two-digit numbers

Comment: My answer is how to calculate how many deferent combinations you can make with let's say 2 digits so Math.pow(9,2) will Output 81 because 9*9 is 81. Therefor with 2 digits you can make 81 combinations

Comment: @McMuffin But there are 90 two-digits numbers 10..99

Comment: @MBo what do you mean?

Comment: What combinations do you count?  (Question author does not define clearly)

Comment: @MBo all possible combinations

Answer (score 0):

Dont know its right or wrong little bit ugly but works fine to me

```js
$('button').click(function() {
a=$('input').val();
c=$('input').val();
b=0;
for(i=1; i<a; i++){
c--;
b+=a*c;
}
if(a==3){
b=6;// i dont wanna think about this anymore
}
$('.num').text(b);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="row" type="text"> number<br>
<button>
Calculate Combination
</button>
<br>
<span>
  Combinations : 
</span>
<span class='num'> </span>
```

Just run and put number of digits of your number if 4321 put 4 etc